# Creat a view with Sharepoint List: Sort by column then filter everything but the most recent

Tags: filter, grouping, sorting

I have a list coming in from forms with a serial number and a date:
[Serial Number] [date]

- a-6/10/19
- a-6/12/12
- a-2/4/14
- b-3/2/15
- b-4/1/12

I want to create a view where I only display the most recent item for each serial number

- a-6/10/19
- b-3/2/15.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using some workaround with the help of **WorkFlow and List View.**

*1.Add one "Yes/No" column named "IsLatest" and set "Default Value=No".*

2.Collect all the available items in the list with the same "SerialNumber-Date" value and "IsLatest" value is "Yes", using Rest API. Loop the items and set "IsLatest" field to "No" for all the items.

3.In the next step, Set "IsLatest" value to "Yes" for the current item.

And do the following change in the view,

- Add one filter, **"IsLatest=Yes"**